# Associate ElasticIP on Start Up using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working with the Amazon javascript/nodejs sdk. I can successfully start an existing instance using the following code but the elastic IP address is not assigned to the instance unless I re-run the code. Based on the errors, it is because the instance is not yet in a 'started' status so it cannot be assigned an elastic IP.

Is there a way to assign an elastic IP to an instance on startup?

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({region: 'us-east-1'});
ec2.startInstances({InstanceIds : ['i-xxxxxxxx'] },function (err, data) {

    var params = {
        InstanceId: 'i-xxxxxxxx',
        PublicIp: '41.222.111.222'
    };
    ec2.associateAddress(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response

       return cb(null, data);
    });

});
```

The only other alternative I can figure is to wait a few minutes after starting, and then test if the instance will accept the elastic IP. I wanted to avoid this if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your instance on ec2-classic, the eip gets disassociated, if you have the instance in EC2-VPC the eip should remain associated.

Here is the documentation from AWS about elastic IPs.

EC2-Classic: We disassociate any Elastic IP address that's associated with the instance. You're charged for Elastic IP addresses that aren't associated with an instance. When you restart the instance, you must associate the Elastic IP address with the instance; we don't do this automatically.

EC2-VPC: The instance retains its associated Elastic IP addresses. You're charged for any Elastic IP addresses associated with a stopped instance.

REF: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html

If you are in ec2-classic, you can always setup a startup script which associates the EIP to the instance.
If you want to do it programmatically, try setting userdata at the time of instance creation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For reference to others, as it turns out the above code does work (based on my testing) and the instance appears to be assigned the EIP as soon as it starts. I am using Lambda functions and did not want the process dependent on a startup script. As a failsafe, I have another lambda function that assigns the EIP to the device a few minutes after the instance is started just in case.